# pointer already defined in file

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this piece of code that works as expected when all of it is in a single file
The problem is i need the platform to have a static pointer to the engine and vice versa

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma region include/iplatform.h
namespace engine {
    class IEngine;
}

namespace platform {
    class IPlatform {
    public:
        virtual ~IPlatform() = default;
        static engine::IEngine* ptrEngine;
    };

    static std::unique_ptr<IPlatform> platform;
    engine::IEngine* platform::IPlatform::ptrEngine = nullptr;
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region include/iengine.h
namespace engine {
    class IEngine {

    };
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region include/engine.h
namespace engine {
    class Engine : public IEngine {
    public:
        Engine();
        void setup();
    };
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region src/enginge.cpp
namespace engine {
    Engine::Engine() { setup(); }

}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region include/platform.h
namespace platform {
    class Platform : public platform::IPlatform{
    public:
        virtual ~Platform() override;
    };
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region src/platform.cpp
namespace platform {
    Platform::~Platform() {

    }
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region src/engine.cpp
namespace engine {
    void Engine::setup() {
        platform::platform = std::make_unique<platform::Platform>();
        platform::platform->ptrEngine = this;
    }
}
#pragma endregion

int main() {
    engine::Engine* e = new engine::Engine();

    std::cout << "" << e << std::endl;
    std::cout << "" << platform::platform->ptrEngine;

    return 0;
}
```

but once i separate it out into files as outlined by the region blocks i start getting errors, the project structure requires us to have headers and source separately

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6031   Return value ignored: 'std::unique_ptr<platform::IPlatform,std::default_delete<platform::IPlatform> >::->'. CPP_BOILERPLATE C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\app\main.cpp    74  
Warning C6031   Return value ignored: 'std::unique_ptr<platform::IPlatform,std::default_delete<platform::IPlatform> >::->'. CPP_BOILERPLATE C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\app\main.cpp    83  
Warning D9025   overriding '/W3' with '/W4' C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cpp-project-masters C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cl  1   
Warning D9025   overriding '/W3' with '/W4' C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cpp-project-masters C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cl  1   
Error   LNK2005 "public: static class engine::IEngine * platform::IPlatform::ptrEngine" (?ptrEngine@IPlatform@platform@@2PEAVIEngine@engine@@EA) already defined in engine.cpp.obj  C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cpp-project-masters C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\platform.cpp.obj    1   
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\cpp-project-masters C:\Users\Tiit\Documents\cpp\cpp-project-masters\out\build\x64-Debug\main.exe    1
```

is there a way to do this

Comment: Move `engine::IEngine* platform::IPlatform::ptrEngine = nullptr;` to a cpp file.

Comment: Note that "region blocks" are not part of standard C++. Also, the meaning of `#pragma` directives is implementation-specific; there are no portable pragmas.

Comment: Thanks @wohlstad, moving the line to a cpp file worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as @wohlstad commented was moving the line

```
engine::IEngine* platform::IPlatform::ptrEngine = nullptr;
```

to one of the source files